# Explode one column and modify another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Havig a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, "this is"], [1, 2, "a sample"], [2, 1, "dataset"]]),
                   columns=['row', 'col', 'word'])

  row   col       word
0   1     1    this is
1   1     2   a sample
2   2     1    dataset
```

I would like to explode the column **word** based on whitespace character and update **col**.

So the expected result dataset, in this case would be:

```
  row   col       word
0   1     1       this
1   1     2         is
2   1     3          a
3   1     4     sample
2   2     1    dataset
```

The exploding based on whitespace character could be achieved by applying:

```
df.assign(word=df['word'].str.split(' ')).explode('word', ignore_index=True)

  row   col      word
0   1     1      this
1   1     1        is
2   1     2         a
3   1     2    sample
4   2     1   dataset
```

But the problem is that **col** obviously is not updating. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
(df.assign(word=df['word'].str.split(' '))
   .explode('word', ignore_index=True)
   .assign(col=lambda x:x.groupby('row').cumcount()+1)
)
```

Output:

```
  row  col     word
0   1    1     this
1   1    2       is
2   1    3        a
3   1    4   sample
4   2    1  dataset
```